# How to read dates from file and exclude them in a date range?

Tags: php

I have written a code to exclude the weekends and holidays between two dates.
But now I want to include the holidays in a file and exclude them.

Code is working fine

```
 <?php

  $joiningdate= date_create($row['jdate']); // Fetching this from database
  $tdate = date('Y-m-d');
  $todaydate1=date_create($tdate);
  $todaydate1->modify('+1 day'); 
  $interval=date_diff($todaydate1,$joiningdate);
  $days = $interval->days;

  // creating an iterateable period of date (P1D equates to 1 day)
  $period = new DatePeriod($joiningdate, new DateInterval('P1D'), $todaydate1);

  // Storing holidays in a array to exclude
  $holidays = array('2019-01-15','2019-01-26','2019-03-04','2019-05-01','2019-08-15','2019-09-02','2019-10-02','2019-09-08', '2019-11-01');

  foreach($period as $dt) {
      $curr = $dt->format('D');

      // substract holidays
      if (in_array($dt->format('Y-m-d'), $holidays)) {
         $days--;
      }

      // substracting if Saturday or Sunday
      if ($curr == 'Sat' || $curr == 'Sun') {
          $days--;
      }
  }
  echo $days;
 ?>
```

I'm getting the output as expected.
But now I need to add the holidays array to a file and exclude them.

Comment: And what is the actual _problem_ with that? I assume you know how include/require work, if not, you can go read up on it … So what part of the problem do you actually need our help for now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a dates.json file and paste all the dates you want to exclude like this

```
    {
      "dates" : [
          "2019-05-01",
          "2019-06-01"
      ]
    }
```

In your php read these dates as

```
$holidays = file_get_contents('dates.json');
$holidays = json_decode($holidays, true);
$holidays = $holidays['dates'];
```

Now you holidays variable has both the dates.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
  $joiningdate= date_create($row['jdate']); // Fetching this from database
  $tdate = date('Y-m-d');
  $todaydate1=date_create($tdate);
  $todaydate1->modify('+1 day'); 
  $interval=date_diff($todaydate1,$joiningdate);
  $days = $interval->days;

  // creating an iterateable period of date (P1D equates to 1 day)
  $period = new DatePeriod($joiningdate, new DateInterval('P1D'), $todaydate1);

  // Storing holidays in a array to exclude
  $holidays = array('2019-01-15','2019-01-26','2019-03-04','2019-05-01','2019-08-15','2019-09-02','2019-10-02','2019-09-08', '2019-11-01');
$return_data_set=array();
  foreach($period as $dt) {
    $curr = $dt->format('D'); 
    // substract holidays
    if (in_array($dt->format('Y-m-d'), $holidays)) { 
        $return_data['holiday'][]=$dt->format('Y-m-d'); 
    }
    else{
        $return_data['working_days'][]=$dt->format('Y-m-d'); 
    }  
}
print_r($return_data['working_days']);
 ?>
```